# How to get an exploded version of "sbt universal:packageBin"?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

I need to build some lib which uses [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/universal.html) and supports `sbt universal:packageBin`, which includes all dependencies of that project and such. For better integration with my own project I would need the produced Zip simply in an exploded form.

Is this possible somehow without extracting the archive on my own? I do that already, just wondered if there's anything easier by simply telling `sbt` to not create the Zip or such. That would only be of benefit to me if I could do that as part of the invocation of the above command, as some shell argument or such. I don't want to change any build file or such.

I didn't find anything in the docs, only creating some [custom forma](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/recipes/custom.html#custom-packaging-format)t or such, which is more work than to simply unzip the archive and it seems that I would need to change build files for that, which I don't want. I want to keep the whole project as it is.

Comment: have you tried depending on the stage task, and using its output?

Comment: No, I don't want to deal with the available build files. I would like to have some shell arg, environment variable or something similar easy and "external".

Comment: @Boris You gave the right hint, I simply didn't understand it properly: One can provide the "stage" task as target on the shell, that's exactly what I needed. `sbt compilerJVM/stage` Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Thorsten ok, done :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to look at the output of the stage task, rather than the packageBin one.